# "Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/*.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf" when installing tex-common

Tags: dpkg, latex

Im having a lot of problems with my Ubuntu after the update from the 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS.

Every time I start the system, it shows a lot of dialogs saying that the system encountered problems, and it gives me the options "OK" and "Report the problem".

Also, my main problem is with `apt-get` not working. For example, when an `upgrade` is executed, it shows problems related to pages of Latex, as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdb5.1-java libdb5.1-java-jni
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
78 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up tex-common (4.04) ...
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/05TeXMF.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/15Plain.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/45TeXinputs.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/55Fonts.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/65BibTeX.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/75DviPS.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/80DVIPDFMx.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/85Misc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/90TeXDoc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/95NonPath.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... 
updmap-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/updmap.F4dMHt02
Please include this file if you report a bug.

Sometimes, not accepting conffile updates in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
causes updmap-sys to fail.  Please check for files with extension
.dpkg-dist or .ucf-dist in this directory

dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-sanskrit:
 latex-sanskrit depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-sanskrit (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lmodern:
 lmodern depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lmodern (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tex-gyre:
 tex-gyre depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tex-gyre (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-base:
 texlive-latex-base depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-recommended:
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cm-super-minimal:
 cm-super-minimal depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 cm-super-minimal depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cm-super-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cm-super:
 cm-super depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 cm-super depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 cm-super depends on cm-super-minimal (= 0.3.4-9); however:
  Package cm-super-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cm-super (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-metapost:
 texlive-metapost depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-metapost (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of context:
 context depends on texlive-metapost (>= 2013); however:
  Package texlive-metapost is not configured yet.
 context depends on lmodern (>= 2.004.4); however:
  Package lmodern is not configured yet.
 context depends on tex-gyre; however:
  Package tex-gyre is not configured yet.
 context depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package context (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of context-modules:
 context-modules depends on context (>> 2011); however:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

  Package context is not configured yet.
 context-modules depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package context-modules (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-font-utils:
 texlive-font-utils depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-font-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-extra-utils:
 texlive-extra-utils depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-extra-utils depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-extra-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of feynmf:
 feynmf depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 feynmf depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 feynmf depends on texlive-font-utils; however:
  Package texlive-font-utils is not configured yet.
 feynmf depends on texlive-extra-utils; however:
  Package texlive-extra-utils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package feynmf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kile:
 kile depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kile (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-xcolor:
 latex-xcolor depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 latex-xcolor depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-xcolor (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-beamer:
 latex-beamer depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on latex-xcolor (>= 2.00-1); however:
  Package latex-xcolor is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texBest Regards,
```

live-latex-base is not configured yet.

```
dpkg: error processing package latex-beamer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-common:
 latex-cjk-common depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-common depends on texlive-font-utils (>= 2007.dfsg.2-1); however:
  Package texlive-font-utils is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-common depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-chinese:
 latex-cjk-chinese depends on latex-cjk-common (= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-chinese depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-chinese (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-japanese:
 latex-cjk-japanese depends on latex-cjk-common (= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-japanese depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-japanese (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-korean:
 latex-cjk-korean depends on latex-cjk-common (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-korean depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-korean (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-other:
 texlive-lang-other depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-other (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-thai:
 latex-cjk-thai depends on latex-cjk-common (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-thai depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-thai depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-thai depends on texlive-lang-other (>= 2013.20130523-1); however:
  Package texlive-lang-other is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-thai (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-all:
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-common (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-chinese (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-chinese is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-japanese (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-japanese is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-korean (= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-korean is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-thai (= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-thai is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-all (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latexmk:
 latexmk depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latexmk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of m-tx:
 m-tx depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package m-tx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of musixtex:
 musixtex depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package musixtex (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pmx:
 pmx depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 pmx depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pmx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of purifyeps:
 purifyeps depends on texlive-metapost; however:
  Package texlive-metapost is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package purifyeps (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-recommended:
 texlive-fonts-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive:
 texlive depends on texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive depends on texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-fonts-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-bibtex-extra:
 texlive-bibtex-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-bibtex-extra depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-bibtex-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-extra:
 texlive-fonts-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-extra-doc:
 texlive-fonts-extra-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-extra-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-recommended-doc:
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-recommended-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-formats-extra:
 texlive-formats-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-formats-extra depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-formats-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-polish:
 texlive-lang-polish depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-lang-polish depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-polish (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-generic-extra:
 texlive-generic-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-generic-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-indic:
 texlive-lang-indic depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-indic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-spanish:
 texlive-lang-spanish depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-spanish (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-omega:
 texlive-omega depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-omega depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-omega (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-cyrillic:
 texlive-lang-cyrillic depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-lang-cyrillic depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-cyrillic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-humanities-doc:
 texlive-humanities-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-humanities-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-english:
 texlive-lang-english depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-english (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fragmaster:
 fragmaster depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 fragmaster depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 fragmaster depends on texlive-extra-utils; however:
  Package texlive-extra-utils is not configured yet.
 fragmaster depends on texlive-font-utils; however:
  Package texlive-font-utils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fragmaster (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-extra-doc:
 texlive-latex-extra-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-extra-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-publishers-doc:
 texlive-publishers-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-publishers-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-european:
 texlive-lang-european depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-european (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-pictures-doc:
 texlive-pictures-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-pictures-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-metapost-doc:
 texlive-metapost-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-metapost-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-science-doc:
 texlive-science-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-science-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: too many errors, stopping
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

These problems never occurred before the update. I tried to remove the latex packages to solve the problem but even for other purposes APT-GET doesn't work.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: Thanks.... I was having the same problem. It works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened to me during and after the upgrade to 14.04.
It seems something is broken in textlive. updmap-sys can't find some files.

I fixed it the following way:

When you run `apt-get -f install` (or autoremove, or whatever triggers the error) you see the following at the beginning of the error:

```
Setting up tex-common (4.04) ...
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/05TeXMF.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/15Plain.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/45TeXinputs.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/55Fonts.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/65BibTeX.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/75DviPS.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/80DVIPDFMx.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/85Misc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/90TeXDoc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/95NonPath.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... 
updmap-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/updmap.FnIqXOSv
Please include this file if you report a bug.
```

You have to take a look into the file mentioned in the second-to-last line:

```
less /tmp/updmap.FnIqXOSv
```

Note: The file name will be different every time.

Scroll down to the end. Take note of all the `.map` files after the line starting with `ERROR`:

```
ERROR:  The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
        antp.map (in /var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)
        comicvn.map (in /var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)
        csother.map (in /var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)
        cstext.map (in /var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)
        fi4.map (in /var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)
        grverb.map (in /var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)
        mscorevn.map (in /var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)
        slantcm.map (in /var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)
        zpeu.map (in /var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)
```

Now open the file `/var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg` with your favorite text editor, I use vi:

```
sudo vi /var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

Search for every `.map` file you noted earlier and comment them out by prepending the line with a `#`.

Afterwards `apt-get -f install` should take a while to configure texlive but it should work.

Comment: +1 I experienced the same problem as the OP with latex after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04. I followed the steps outlined in this answer by fronk and now it's working fine. For the record, I had to comment out just 4 map files; antp.map, fi4.map, slantcm.map, and zpeu.map.  Hopefully this helps others.

Answer (score 3):

Even the output of `sudo apt-get install -f` was the same as before.

I just could solve the problem by removing the packages related to latex as follow

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove texlive-base
sudo apt-get --purge remove tex-common
sudo apt-get --purge remove texinfo
```

And after that I did as suggested, executing `sudo apt-get install -f` and after `sudo apt-get autoremove`. Apparently all dependencies were resolved.

Answer (score 1):

```
Setting up tex-common (4.04) ...
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/05TeXMF.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/15Plain.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/45TeXinputs.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/55Fonts.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/65BibTeX.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/75DviPS.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/80DVIPDFMx.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/85Misc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/90TeXDoc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/95NonPath.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... 
updmap-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/updmap.F4dMHt02
Please include this file if you report a bug.

Sometimes, not accepting conffile updates in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
causes updmap-sys to fail.  Please check for files with extension
.dpkg-dist or .ucf-dist in this directory
```

While configuring the package `tex-common` there were some errors about certain configuration files. Removing these files should have fixed the problem:

```
sudo rm /etc/texmf/texmf.d/05TeXMF.cnf /etc/texmf/texmf.d/15Plain.cnf /etc/texmf/texmf.d/45TeXinputs.cnf /etc/texmf/texmf.d/55Fonts.cnf /etc/texmf/texmf.d/65BibTeX.cnf /etc/texmf/texmf.d/75DviPS.cnf /etc/texmf/texmf.d/80DVIPDFMx.cnf /etc/texmf/texmf.d/85Misc.cnf /etc/texmf/texmf.d/90TeXDoc.cnf /etc/texmf/texmf.d/95NonPath.cnf
```

Then running `sudo dpkg --configure tex-common` and installing the packages per usual.