# Problem configuring texlive-base

Tags: apt, texlive

I've had some problems with apt-get updates since upgrading to 14.04. It always ends up reporting errors configuring some packages. Here's the logs that appear relevant:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure texlive-base
Setting up texlive-base (2013.20140215-1) ...
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
/usr/bin/tl-paper: setting paper size for dvips to letter.
/usr/bin/tl-paper: setting paper size for dvipdfmx to letter.
/usr/bin/tl-paper: setting paper size for xdvi to letter.
/usr/bin/tl-paper: setting paper size for pdftex to letter.
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Building format(s) --all.
    This may take some time... 
fmtutil-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/fmtutil.gOlunVjQ
Please include this file if you report a bug.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-base (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 texlive-base
$ sudo cat /tmp/fmtutil.gOlunVjQ
fmtutil: running `luatex -ini   -jobname=dviluatex -progname=dviluatex dviluatex.ini'     ...
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013121407 (rev 4627)  (INITEX)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/config/dviluatex.ini
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/config/luatexiniconfig.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/config/luatex-unicode-letters.tex
loading Unicode properties)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/config/etex.ini
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/etex.src
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/base/plain.tex
Preloading the plain format: codes, registers, parameters, fonts,
! Font \tenrm=cmr10 not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
\font 
l.401 \font
         \preloaded=cmr9
? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
\font 
l.401 \font
         \preloaded=cmr9
No pages of output.
Transcript written on dviluatex.log.
```

I'm not sure what's going on, although I did remove some fonts and languages that were taking up a lot of space. How can I fix these errors?

**Edit:** Here is the result of `sudo apt-get install -f:`

```
        Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up tex-common (4.04) ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... 
updmap-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/updmap.0OywwRgl
Please include this file if you report a bug.

Sometimes, not accepting conffile updates in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
causes updmap-sys to fail.  Please check for files with extension
.dpkg-dist or .ucf-dist in this directory

dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-base:
 texlive-latex-base depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-extra-utils:
 texlive-extra-utils depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-extra-utils depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-extra-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-recommended:
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                               No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                       is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-extra:
 texlive-latex-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-latex-extra depends on texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of doxygen-latex:
 doxygen-latex depends on texlive-extra-utils; however:
  Package texlive-extra-utils is not configured yet.
 doxygen-latex depends on texlive-latex-extra; however:
  Package texlive-latex-extra is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package doxygen-latex (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configurNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
       ation of feynmf:
 feynmf depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 feynmf depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 feynmf depends on texlive-extra-utils; however:
  Package texlive-extra-utils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package feynmf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mediawiki-math-texvc:
 mediawiki-math-texvc depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 mediawiki-math-texvc depends on texlive-latex-extra; however:
  Package texlive-latex-extra is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mediawiki-math-texvc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mediawiki-extensions-math:
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                               mediawiki-extensions-math depends on mediawiki-math-texvc (>= 2:1.0); however:
  Package mediawiki-math-texvc is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mediawiki-extensions-math (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive:
 texlive depends on texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-pstricks:
 texlive-pstricks depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-pstricks (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-xetex:
 texlive-xetex depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-xetex depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-xetex (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fragmaster:
 fragmaster depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 fragmaster depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 fragmaster depends on texlive-extra-utils; however:
  Package texlive-extra-utils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fragmaster (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
 texlive-latex-base
 texlive-extra-utils
 texlive-latex-recommended
 texlive-latex-extra
 doxygen-latex
 feynmf
 mediawiki-math-texvc
 mediawiki-extensions-math
 texlive
 texlive-pstricks
 texlive-xetex
 fragmaster
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
$ sudo cat /tmp/updmap.0OywwRgl
updmap: resetting $HOME value (was /home/user) to root's actual home (/root).
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg file for writing changes:
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"

ERROR:  The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
    Acorn.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    Alegreya.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    AnnSton.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    AnonymousPro.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    ArrowsADF.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    ArtNouv.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    ArtNouvc.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    BulletsADF.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    Carrickc.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    CountriesOfEurope.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    EBGaramond.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    ESSTIX.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    Eichenla.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    Eileen.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    EileenBl.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    Elzevier.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    GotIn.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    GoudyIn.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    Kinigcap.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    Konanur.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    Kramer.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    LibreBaskerville.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    LibreCaslon.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    LobsterTwo.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    MnSymbol.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    MorrisIn.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    Nouveaud.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    OrnementsADF.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    Raleway.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    Romantik.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    Rothdn.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    RoyalIn.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    Sanremo.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    SourceCodePro.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    SourceSansPro.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    Starburst.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    Typocaps.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    XCharter.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    Zallman.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    accanthis.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    allrunes.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    antt.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    ap.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    archaicprw.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    arev.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    arevvn.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    ascii.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    aspectratio.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    augie.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    auncial.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    aurical.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    bbold.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    belleek.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    bera.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    bguq.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    boondox.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    cabin.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    calligra.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    cantarell.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    ccicons.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    chartervn.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    cherokee.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    cjhebrew.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    clm.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    cm-lgc.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    cmbrightvn.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    cmin.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    cmll.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    comfortaa.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    concretevn.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    cyklop.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    dejavu-type1.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    dictsym.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    droid.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    dstroke.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    dutchcal.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    epigrafica.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    epiolmec.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    esint.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    esvect.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    eurosym.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    fbb.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    fdsymbol.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    fetamont.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    fge.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    foekfont.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    fonetika.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    fourier-utopia-expert.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    fourier.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    frcursive.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    gentium-type1.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    gfsartemisia.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    gfsbodoni.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    gfscomplutum.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    gfsdidot.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    gfsneohellenic.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    gfssolomos.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    gillius.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    gptimes.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    grotesqvn.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    hacm.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    hfbright.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    icelandic.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    ipaex-type1.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    iwona.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    knitfont.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    kpfonts.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    kurier.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    lato.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    libertine.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    linearA.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    lxfonts.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    manfnt.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    marvosym.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    mathabx.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    mdbch.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    mdgreek.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    mdici.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    mdpgd.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    mdpus.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    mdput.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    mdsymbol.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    mdugm.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    merriweather.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    mintspirit.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    nectec.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    newpx.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    newtx.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    nf.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    ocrb.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    oinuit.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    opensans.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    paratype-type1.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    pbsi.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    phaistos.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    pigpen.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    prodint.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    pxfonts.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    pxtx.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    quattrocento.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    recycle.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    rsfs.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    rsfso.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    sansmathaccent.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    sansmathfonts.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    semaf.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    sqrcaps.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    starfont.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    stix.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    superiors.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    syriac.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    tfrupee.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    tlwg.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    trajan.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    troff-updmap.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    txfonts.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    txttvn.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    uag.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    uaq.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    ubk.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    ucr.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    ugq.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    uhv.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    unc.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    upl.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    urwvn.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    usy.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    utm.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    uzc.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    uzd.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    vnrother.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    vnrtext.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    vntopia.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    wasy.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    xypic.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    ybd.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    ybv.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    yes.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    yfrak.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    yly.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    yrd.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    yv1.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    yv2.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    yv3.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    yvo.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    yvt.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    zi4.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)

    Did you run mktexlsr?

    You can disable non-existent map entries using the option
      --syncwithtrees.
```

Comment: How exactly did you "remove some fonts and languages"?

Comment: @steeldriver Went to usage analyser, then deleted folders through nautilus. I think they were in /usr/share somewhere, but I'm not sure. Can you tell me which files to look for that might be missing and causing this? I'd reinstall them if I knew which packages they were in.

Comment: They're probably part of the texlive-base package itself - you could try reinstalling the package i.e. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall texlive-base`

Comment: @steeldriver `E: Internal Error, No file name for texlive-base:amd64`

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/q/454550/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to post the commands that worked for me, in order:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends texlive-lang-other texlive-latex-extra tex-common texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-pictures texlive-metapost
sudo apt-get install -f texlive-lang-other texlive-latex-extra tex-common texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-pictures texlive-metapost
sudo mktexlsr
sudo updmap-sys
```

Depending on what *.map files are generating the errors, you may need to purge different packages. I searched online for each *.map error for what package it was in, then purged it, reinstalled, and `mktexlsr` and `updmap-sys`. Eventually there were no more errors.

Comment: I don't think the updmap.sys program (or .map files) had anything at all to do with the OP's problem: that was a trigger for the error message, but the underlying error was the misconfigured tex-common which prevents everything else being configured.

Comment: @Peter I was the OP and those commands actually worked for me at the time.

Comment: Hey, I had the same error messages as you, and got to admit @PeterFlynn 's comment may be right, as just purging tex-common and reinstalling resolved the failure as well

Comment: I think I had the same problem as OP and running the commands above did resolve my apt hell. I run Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.