# Problems with upgrade to Ubuntu 14

Tags: apt, upgrade

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 14 a couple of weeks ago I've been unable to install or update any software using apt or the regular updates. When using apt-get I always get the error message 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Any help would be greatly appreciated (there are other issues since updating,
but it seems impossible to fix them without fixing this problem first)

Dan Kennefick

My most recent attempt to run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

returned the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libquvi-scripts libquvi7
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
29 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up tex-common (4.04) ...
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/05TeXMF.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/15Plain.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/45TeXinputs.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/55Fonts.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/65BibTeX.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/75DviPS.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/80DVIPDFMx.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/85Misc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/90TeXDoc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/95NonPath.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... 
updmap-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/updmap.PNtFjpz1
Please include this file if you report a bug.

Sometimes, not accepting conffile updates in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
causes updmap-sys to fail.  Please check for files with extension
.dpkg-dist or .ucf-dist in this directory

dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lmodern:
 lmodern depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lmodern (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tex-gyre:
 tex-gyre depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tex-gyre (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-base:
 texlive-latex-base depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-recommended:
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-xcolor:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 latex-xcolor depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 latex-xcolor depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-xcolor (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-beamer:
 latex-beamer depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on latex-xcolor (>= 2.00-1); however:
  Package latex-xcolor is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-beamer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of maxima-test:
 maxima-test depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package maxima-test (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-extra-utils:
 texlive-extra-utils depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-extra-utils depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-extra-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-font-utils:
 texlive-font-utils depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-font-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-extra:
 texlive-fonts-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-extra-doc:
 texlive-fonts-extra-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-extra-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-recommended:
 texlive-fonts-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-recommended-doc:
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-recommended-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-generic-recommended:
 texlive-generic-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-generic-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-base-doc:
 texlive-latex-base-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-base-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-pictures:
 texlive-pictures depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-pictures (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-extra:
 texlive-latex-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-latex-extra depends on texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive-latex-extra depends on texlive-pictures (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-pictures is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-publishers:
 texlive-publishers depends on texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive-publishers depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-publishers depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-publishers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-extra-doc:
 texlive-latex-extra-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-extra-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-publishers-doc:
 texlive-publishers-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-publishers-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-recommended-doc:
 texlive-latex-recommended-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-recommended-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-luatex:
 texlive-luatex depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-luatex (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-math-extra:
 texlive-math-extra depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-math-extra depends on texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-fonts-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive-math-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-math-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-pictures-doc:
 texlive-pictures-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-pictures-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-pstricks:
 texlive-pstricks depends on texlive-generic-recommended (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-generic-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive-pstricks depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-pstricks (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-pstricks-doc:
 texlive-pstricks-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-pstricks-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tipa:
 tipa depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 tipa depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tipa (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xmaxima:
 xmaxima depends on maxima-test (>= 5.32.1-1); however:
  Package maxima-test is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xmaxima (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: related: [“Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/*.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf” when installing tex-common](http://askubuntu.com/q/454550)